# VBA with runtime error 1004 range of selecting

Tags: excel, select, vba

This is part of the code for a tool which combine two kind of software documents together and analysis the data to generate the charts or reports. and this tool has been used for a long time. but recentely the header of columns for this one perticular documents has been changed. so the tool couldnt well functioning any more. when running this porgrem. The debugger shows the error 1004 with range selecting issue when importing data from the new file. Appreciated for the help.

```
Sub Datenzusammenfügen(nomdoc As String, x As Integer)

Dim LZ As Long
Dim LS As Long
Dim LZe As Long
Dim LSe As Long

LS = Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(3, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
LZ = Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


blatterstellen "inter2SAP", nomdoc, 5

Workbooks(nomdoc).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(3, 1), Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(LZ, LS)), _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="SAPGesamt", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Partnerobjekt")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Partnerobjektart")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Cost Center")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Leistungsart")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 4
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Bereich in SAP")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 5
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").PivotFields("OBS element SAP")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 6
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
End With

k = 7
    Do While Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(2, k).Value <> ""

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Jan"), "Summe von Jan", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Feb"), "Summe von Feb ", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Mrz"), "Summe von Mrz", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Apr"), "Summe von Apr", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Mai"), "Summe von Mai", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Jun"), "Summe von Jun", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Jul"), "Summe von Jul", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Aug"), "Summe von Aug", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Sep"), "Summe von Sep", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Okt"), "Summe von Okt", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Nov"), "Summe von Nov", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "SAPGesamt").PivotFields("Dez"), "Summe von Dez", xlSum

k = k + 12
Loop

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SAPGesamt")
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
End With


Battloeschen "inter1SAP", nomdoc

LZe = Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
LSe = Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(2, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column


Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 1), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 1)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 2).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 2), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 2)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 3).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 3), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 3)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 5).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 4), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 4)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 7).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 5), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 5)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 8).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 6), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, 6)).Copy
Sheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Select
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 11).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(3, 7), _
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(LZe, LSe)).Copy
Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("Rohdaten SAP " & x).Cells(4, 17).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Battloeschen "inter2SAP", nomdoc
formatertableau nomdoc, "Rohdaten SAP " & x, LZe, 3, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error is raised?

Comment: Workbooks(nomdoc).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(3, 1), Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(LZ, LS)), _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="SAPGesamt", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

Comment: Suspicion: LZ = 3? Or another suspicion: There is already a pivot table in Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter2SAP").Cells(1, 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the `Range` you're using in the line:

`Workbooks(nomdoc).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _ Range(Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(3, 1), Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP").Cells(LZ, LS)), _ Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable`

Because you haven't specified a worksheet before the `Range` object, it tries to find it on the active sheet.

Try something like this:

```
Dim PivotRange as Range
With Workbooks(nomdoc).Worksheets("inter1SAP")
    Set PivotRange = .Range(.Cells(3,1), .Cells(LZ, LS))
End With

Workbooks(nomdoc).PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=PivotRange, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable... etc.
```

That's untested so don't copy/paste it straight in as it might have other errors, but I think it should set you in the right direction.